# How do I translate the sizings of a Lenovo Tab M8 into pixels for Figma?

Tags: android, tablet, figma

My company has a Android app. Our clients view the app with a Lenovo Tab M8. I am a designer tasked with recreating the current app experience in Figma so that our design team can have a design system and make accurate mockups. But I'm struggling to capture basic measurements (my experience is in Web and not Native apps).

The first question is, what is the width and length of the screen in pixels? I'm trying to create a basic screen template in Figma. I know the Lenovo display is 1280x800px with 16:10 screen ratio. But when I create a 1280x800 frame in Figma it's significantly larger than the physical device. I'm a little lost.

The other question is, I'm trying to recreate font sizes but I know the app uses dp and not px. I found a site that convert them, but I don't know if the tablet is LDPI, MDPI, or whatever.

https://www.pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter

Thanks for any insights you have.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to know what density the tablet is, the point of using *dp* (*density-independent pixels*) is that everything will look pretty much the same size in the real world. The baseline density is *LDPI*, which is *160 pixels per inch* - so *160dp* is *one inch* on the screen.

*XHDPI* is *320 pixels per inch*, so double the density - but converting *160dp* to pixels on XHDPI devices involves multiplying it by *2*, so the result is *320 pixels* - which again corresponds to *1 inch* on a *320dpi* screen. See how it works?

So the pixel resolution isn't important, a tablet will be large in *dp* terms because they're physically bigger than a phone, more inches and all that. But if you're curious, if your *M8* is the 2nd-gen one, according to the tech specs it's *4.8"* on the *800 px* axis (the one with the smallest bezels), and that works out to *166.7 DPI* without taking those bezels into account - so it's an *LDPI* device!

I don't know anything about Figma, but so long as you're using *dp* measurements it should work ok? You have to be aware of the size of your screen though - when you said you created a frame *800 high* and it was too big, if that was *800**dp*** then *800 / 160* is *5"* and your screen is only *4.8"* high. Ideally your layout shouldn't require a specific physical size though, it should be able to adjust since different devices (even very similar ones) are different sizes - but I don't know how Figma works with that! That's just the way it works for the standard Android stuff

---

Also ideally fonts should use **sp** which is like *dp* but it has an additional scaling step depending on the user's font size settings on the device - it lets them shrink or enlarge text to their preference and for accessibility (the latter is especially important). Sometimes you want a fixed size for something that's more of a graphic element, but generally text should be scalable

If you want to know how to convert, have a look at [the Material Type System](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html) - there's a chart there for converting between different units (also *1sp = 1dp* for the *Normal* text size FYI). There's also a tool on there to create a *type scale* but only for stuff on Google Fonts - just saves you doing it yourself!